Cannot connect to Lora E5 mini (STM32WLE5JC)
So now I try to program a LoRa-E5-mini in STM32 IDE. When i try to connect to the LoRa it says:
Error: No STM32 target found! If your product embeds Debug Authentication, please perform a discovery using Debug Authentication.
I connected the VTREF (to 3.3V on LoRa), SWDIO (to DIO on LoRa), SWCLK (to CLK on LoRa), GND (to GND on LoRa) to the LoRa.
[STM32CubeProgrammer]

[Pinout]

I tried to press the reset button while connecting, also switch the mode to connect under reset and the reset mode to software reset. I also updated the firmware but it seems it does not help. Also googled a lot but still did not find a solution.
Under the usb devices (in the device manager) the STM32 STLink is present.

The SWD clock and data are PA13 and PA14 alternate function 0, which is enabled by default upon power on reset. I noticed you're connecting under reset, but you never mentioned connecting reset pin. Try connecting not under reset. Any difference?

Connecting the reset pin should help.

Tried to connect not under reset, also with connected reset pin but none of these works.

The other solution would be to put the device in DFU mode and connect via USB. I do that with most of my STM32 boards. Does this board have the BOOTØ pin exposed?

Yes it has a BOOT0 pin exposed.

BOOTØ to Vcc. Plug in USB. Select UART in the menu (instead of STLink or USB). Select the port. Click connect.

It did not help :(
